# Grails. How to save entity with nested list?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

There are the following entities:

```
class Letter {
    String email          
    String subject
    String content

    List attachments

    static hasMany = [attachments : Attachment]

    static constraints = {
        subject nullable:true, blank:true
        content nullable:true
        email email:true
        attachments nullable:true
    }
```

and

```
class Attachment {
    String fileName
    Integer size
    byte[] data
    Letter letter

    static belongsTo = [letter:Letter]
    static constraints = {
        fileName nullable: true, blank: true
        size nullable: true, blank: true
        data nullable: true, maxSize: 1024*1024*5 /*5MB*/
    }
```

}

In a separate module creates a letter and attachments are added to this list. Without persisting. Code:

```
public Letter createLetterFromMessage(Message message) {
    Letter letter = new Letter()

    def addr = message.getFrom()[0]
    if (addr instanceof InternetAddress) {
        def inAddr = addr as InternetAddress
        letter.email = inAddr.address
    }

    letter.subject = message.subject

    def part = message as Part
    letter.attachments = getAttachmetList(letter,part.getContent())//list of not persisted attaches

    return letter
}
```

In another module I need to save an letter with already added the list of attachments.
Code:

```
    public void onSuccess(List<Letter> letters) {
        for (Letter letter : letters) {
            if(letterService.save(letter)){
                log.debug "Letter saved with id = ${letter.id}."
                //do some work
            } else
                log.debug "Letter not saved and not added to execution context!"
        }
   }
```

How to do this?

An example from the documentation does not work here.

```
def book = new Book(title: 'Misery')
author.addToBooks(book)
author.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you simply assign the letter instance to `letter` property of each attachment, and then save the letter instance, it should propagate save to each attachment:

```
letter.attachments.each{ it.letter = letter }
letter.save()
```

this is essentially what `addTo*` method does

Comment: Thanks, now everything works. this solution is more appropriate for me.

Answer (score 0):

This part in `createLetterFromMessage`:

```
....
def part = message as Part
letter.attachments = getAttachmetList(letter,part.getContent())//list of not persisted attaches
return letter
...
```

should be

```
getAttachmetList(letter,part.getContent()).each { Attachment a ->
    letter.addToAttachments(a)
}
```

Then you should just save Letter instance and Attachments will be persisted as well.

Otherwise @injecteer suggestion should be used